# Eclipse plugin-how to programmability select "copy project into workspace"?

Tags: eclipse, import, eclipse-plugin, copy

I'm writing a plugin for eclipse on windows 7. I want that when somebody opens eclipse that contains my plugin in it, and clicks right click->import->existing projects into workspace, the "copy projects into workspace" checkbox will be automatically checked. 
I have a startup extension class that is called on the eclipse ui startup event, maybe I can add there, or anywhere else, a snippet that doing so?
I googled 2 days continuous, but found nothing :(

Comment: I don't see any way to set this option that does not involve using internal classses (which are off limits).